# How do I enable digest auth for Jetty fronting Elastic Search

Tags: authentication, jetty, http-authentication, elasticsearch, digest

We've gotten Jetty running the HTTP front end of Elastic Search with BASIC authentication. We would like to use DIGEST authentication instead, but the [Jetty](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/configuring-security.html#configuring-security-authentication) documentation is hard to reconcile with the [Jetty Elastic Search](https://github.com/sonian/elasticsearch-jetty) documentation; in particular, we're not sure where in the configuration chain we need to set the authentication method (the "auth-method" node in the Jetty docs).

FYI, we are using the stock [jetty.xml](https://github.com/sonian/elasticsearch-jetty/blob/master/config/jetty.xml), [jetty-hash-auth.xml](https://github.com/sonian/elasticsearch-jetty/blob/master/config/jetty-hash-auth.xml), and [jetty-restrict-all.xml](https://github.com/sonian/elasticsearch-jetty/blob/master/config/jetty-restrict-all.xml) files.

FYI, we did see the word "BASIC" in the jetty-restrict-all.xml file, but changing that to "DIGEST" did not seem to enable digest authentication.

Has anybody been able to get this combination to work?